# Quick way to get user's signature in PHP

Tags: custom-fields, database, query, sessions

I'm just wondering if there is a quick way to get a user's signature using something like the session class? For example to grab the active user's email from the session class you can simply call $this->EE->session->userdata('email');

I am referring to the native signature value also, and not a custom member field.

I would prefer to avoid running a secondary database query to get the information as time is definitely an issue in our case.

Cheers, 
Conor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this to see if it works for you. I just tested, and it works just fine for me.

```
$this->EE->session->userdata('signature')
```

To see all the values in the session values stored as userdata, just do the following:

```
var_dump($this->EE->session->userdata);
exit();
```

Comment: Excellent thanks, seems like the docs on the userdata object aren't as conclusive as they perhaps should be in that case. The above should have easy given a trial and error approach obviously but it would be great, especially for developers who are new to the platform to have a full view of Expression Engine's capabilities. Thanks again!

Comment: Haha, yeah the dev docs aren't the best. Do yourself a favor and just start reading the code (it usually saves me a lot of time). I wouldn't have gotten anywhere if I relied on the docs!

Comment: That's generally what I do also, but I thought the docs for the userdata object appeared to be quite elaborate. Let that be a lesson to everyone I suppose! print_r and var_dump are your friend for all things EE related.